# How to calculate average on a column with JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, average

I would like to calculate average on a column.
I tried the following:

```
@Query("SELECT AVG(e.rating) FROM user_rating e WHERE e.route_uid = ?1")
fun averageOfRateings(routeId: UUID): Long
```

The query works in Sql, however I get the following error when I run the code in Spring Boot.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
user_rating is not mapped [SELECT AVG(e.rating) FROM user_rating e WHERE e.route_uid = ?1]
```

What would be the right syntax? What is the problem with the mapping of my table?

Comment: like mentioned in the answer. Your `user_rating` should be exactly spelled like your entity name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you must use the entity name, not the table.The same applies for the column name, you must use the field name instead.

I assume your entity is UserRating, so the correct query will be:

```
@Query("SELECT AVG(e.rating) FROM UserRating e WHERE e.routeUid = ?1")
```

Or second option specify that is native query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT AVG(e.rating) FROM user_rating e WHERE e.route_uid = ?1" , nativeQuery = true)
```